# Am I misusing the GitHub API? If so, what's the alternative?

Tags: api, http-headers

I'm working on my personal website: https://aleksandrhovhannisyan.github.io/

Currently, all of my projects are hardcoded in the HTML. This makes it difficult to maintain them. For example, if a project gets starred, I have to go in and manually update the star count and then push a commit. It works, and it's fast from a user experience perspective, but it's inefficient.

I've been working on an alternative that automatically populates the projects section of my site with cards based on data pulled from the GitHub API for repos:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

According to the top-level API documentation (https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required):

> All API requests MUST include a valid `User-Agent` header. Requests with no `User-Agent` header will be rejected. We request that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the `User-Agent` header value. This allows us to contact you if there are problems.

Indeed, that's true. As I was working on my script and refreshing my page locally, I eventually got blocked with a 403 forbidden error because I hadn't been setting the `User-Agent` header.

But there's a problem: When I open my site in Chrome, the console shows this error:

> index.js:51 Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

My understanding is that this is an appropriate precaution and that the user agent header should really be set on some sort of server. Chrome does eventually load the data, albeit more slowly than Firefox, which doesn't seem to impose any such restriction on `User-Agent` use.

Is a personal website like mine not a good candidate for using the GitHub API and setting the `User-Agent` request header? If so, what alternative options do I have except hardcoding everything?

Comment: The browser will add that header for you, but you shouldn't be making API requests directly from the client because it exposes your credentials.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems the GitHub API doesn't require you to create a client ID to authenticate. I've just been able to make `XMLHttpRequest`s without authentication. Is that what you meant re: exposing credentials?

Comment: If you're hitting something like `https://api.github.com/users/:user/repos` you don't need authentication. Was there a specific message that made you think the User-Agent was the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, no, I'm requesting `https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo-name`. For example, `https://api.github.com/repos/AleksandrHovhannisyan/Scribe-Text-Editor`.

Comment: Same applies to `/users/:user/:repo`, I can access that specific repo's details just fine. There may be different rate limits in play without an auth token, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. So would you advise I get rid of the `setRequestHeader` call? If it isn't obvious, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to working with APIs and making HTTP requests :)

Comment: It does seem like I have a rate limit of 60 requests per hour. I got that info by using `curl` as demonstrated here: https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that my script makes 12 API requests per refresh—6 for the repo content (one per repo), and 6 more for the repo topics (which must be submitted as separate requests because it's currently a preview feature)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is not so much about setting the `User-Agent` header as it is about the number of requests I was making.

According to GitHub's own documentation:

> For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60 requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with the originating IP address, and not the user making requests.

This wouldn't matter for my end users, since they wouldn't be refreshing my site so many times (hopefully), but it did matter for testing/development because I was frequently refreshing to see the results of my changes (and therefore using up my available requests). I checked this by spamming refresh and running `curl -i https://api.github.com/users/my-username` per https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting:

[image]

The reason I ran out of requests so quickly is because of a flaw in my JavaScript design: I make one separate request for each repo I'm interested in. Instead, what I'll likely do is create a dictionary with URLs for the repos that I am interested in displaying and then make a single request for all public repos on my account. I can then run through each repo and check if it's in the list of repos I want to show; if it is, I'll proceed with creating a project card for it. That way, I'm not spamming 6 requests each time I refresh just to get the repo information.